# SWT Browser crash while using ext-base.js iframe

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am using RCP eclipse to build product.
Using SWT Browser to view web site but whenever using ext-base.js and iframe in this Brower,
it is happan to crash entire application.
Thanks in advance.

Hi Baz,
Thanks for your quick reply.
My question is why SWT Browser is going to crash to open this type of web site.

```
browser.evaluate(EVENT_SCRIPT);
```

I am getting fatal error. Its log like :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6eddaf6b, pid=10032, tid=4388
#
# JRE version: 6.0_31-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.6-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jscript9.dll+0x6af6b]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# E:\eclipse_group\eclipse_indigo_2.0\hs_err_pid10032.log

#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: So what is your question? What error message do you get? Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Quite a few bug reports in Eclipse for EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION, more details would help to see if this matches any of them. The hs_err_10032.log has lots of info.

Comment: But I am not able to find any idea from hs_err_pid10032.log